# JQuery bind on multiple same name ID

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bind

I have one table generated by PHP

```
<div class="mailbox-list">
    <ul>
    <?php while ($row=$database->fetch_array($result)){?>
        <li id="emal_new" name="<?php echo $row["id"];?>">
            <a href="#" >
            <div class="mail-checkbox">
                <input class="filled-in" id="<?php echo $row["id"];?>" type="checkbox">
                <label for="<?php echo $row["id"];?>"></label>
            </div>
            <h5 class="mail-author">VPN Access Manager</h5>
            <h4 class="mail-title"><?php echo $row["naslov"]; ?></h4>
            <p class="hide-on-small-and-down mail-text">
            <?php $poruka_kratka = clear_mail($row['poruka']);
            echo text($poruka_kratka,"75")?></p>
            <div class="position-top-right p f-12 mail-date"><?php echo $row["datum"]; ?></div>

            </a>
        <div id ="user-result" />
        </li>

    <?php }?>  
    </ul>
</div>
```

And my JQCODE is:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var x_timer;    
$("#emal_new").bind('click', function (e){
clearTimeout(x_timer);
var email_id = $(this).attr("name");
x_timer = setTimeout(function(){
check_email_id_ajax(email_id);
}, 100);
});


function check_email_id_ajax(email_id){
$("#user-result").html('<img style="width: 24px; height:24px;" src="<?php echo WWW; echo 'includes/themes/'.THEME_NAME.'';?>/img/ajax.gif" />');
$.post('ajax/mailbox.php',{'email_id':email_id}, function(data) {
$("#user-result").html(data);
});
}

});
</script>
```

And i have about 30 and more data in table and only first at table works with that jquery bind? How can bind work on all

objects?

I need when i click on some row in table call ajax for more information about that row called by name.

Thanks!

Comment: **ID should be unique**

Comment: it's not relevant to give same `ID` it should be unique one

Comment: Need to use `class` instead of `id`

Comment: Thansk to all its help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviors as Identifiers in HTML must be unique, Use a common class to bind event handlers, also I would recommend you to use `data-*` prefix custom attribute to store arbitary data, which can be accessed using `.data()`

Change the HTML as

```
 <li class="emal_new" data-name="<?php echo $row["id"];?>">
     <div class="user-result"></div>
 </li>
```

*Script*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x_timer;
    $(".emal_new").on('click', function(e) {

        var email_id = $(this).data("name");
      var userResult = $(this).find('.user-result')

        if (x_timer)
            clearTimeout(x_timer);
        x_timer = setTimeout(function() {
            check_email_id_ajax(email_id);
        }, 100);
    });


    function check_email_id_ajax(userResult, email_id) {
        userResult.html(TheHTML);

        $.post('ajax/mailbox.php', {
            'email_id': email_id
        }, function(data) {
            userResult.html(data);
        });
    }
});
```

Also not [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/Bind/) has been deprecated. It was superseded by the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method for attaching event handlers to a document since jQuery 1.7

Comment: satpal don't you think his function code is not correct and need to be outside of document ready?

Comment: @AlivetoDie, I missed `userResult` thing and why do they needs to outside  document ready and I have mentioned `.on()`

Comment: satpal it's ok, but change `bind` to `on`